# Why would I need to run docker privileged to access host log4j2.yaml

Tags: java, docker, centos, log4j2, docker-volume

I've got a centos 7 image in a centos 7 host.
My entrypoint uses -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/opt/foo/bar/log4j2.yaml
I use a -v switch to share /home/fooser/log4j2.yaml:/opt/foo/bar/log4j2.yaml
When I just use --cap-add SYS_ADMIN (I need samba access), log4j is unable to access it's config file; however, if I use --privileged, everything works. I understand I must need an additional capability, but have no idea what it would be.

Comment: What are the permissions of `log4j2.yaml` on the host? They may not be readable by the user in the Docker container.

Comment: @Ownaginatious I tried with 666 and 777

Comment: What about the parent directories? They also need execute by anybody to be able to get to the file.